# BC30451 'RegistryValueKind' is not declared

Tags: vb.net, registry, regedit, dword

I want to try change Internet Settings Level with `VB.NET`

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\", True)

    regKey.SetValue("2400", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord)

End Sub

End Class
```

I get this error :
**BC30451   'RegistryValueKind' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level**.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you wanting to change it for current user or all users. I believe that's your problem, all users....

Comment: Looks like maybe you don't have an import for `Microsoft.Win32`, so perhaps `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord` is what you need?

Comment: @Mark `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord` isn't a valid namespace and `RegistryValueKind` is an Enum...

Comment: @Codexer It wasn't at all clear from my cryptic comment :-), but I was suggesting that without the import for `Microsoft.Win32`, qualifying the `RegistryValueKind` reference would be required, e.g. `regKey.SetValue("2400", 0, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)` (everything else was qualified, so I assumed the import wasn't there).  I didn't look up the API docs to see if anything else was correct... hopefully your answer gets them what they need.

Answer (score 0):

First when you run your code, you should throw an exception when trying to set `regKey =` its instance is nothing. When trying to use it, it will fail. You error message is as states from not importing: `Import Microsoft.Win32` namespace as @Mark had mentioned. When you actually import this namespace you will have the issue I mentioned above... Please see my solution below.

**Tried & Tested**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\", True)
    If regKey IsNot Nothing Then regKey.SetValue("2400", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord) : regKey.Close()

End Sub
```

I could change this back and fourth as well. Please don't forget to `Close` the key after you are done, in my code it's doing that.